# Failed to invoke updateStatus. Message payload is of type: String

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio

i just started with `Mule` i was creating a very simple example using `twitter`

i'm using `mule 3.5` i started with creating `New Example Project` then the `Hello world`

now i'm using `twitter` and every thing looks okay when i use `show user` i get the Json object but when i do `update status` i get this error message :

```
 Failed to invoke updateStatus. Message payload is of type: String
```

Here is my XML

```
<flow name="TwitterUserID" doc:name="TwitterUserID">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"
        doc:description="This endpoint receives an HTTP message." />
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <twitter:update-status config-ref="Twitter" doc:name="Twitter" status="This is from
        Mule "/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
</flow>
```

**Error**

```
Root Exception stack trace:
twitter4j.internal.org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["text"] not found.
at twitter4j.internal.org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:395)
at twitter4j.internal.org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:509)
at twitter4j.internal.json.StatusJSONImpl.init(StatusJSONImpl.java:166)
+ 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

WARN  2014-01-27 08:57:13,406 [[hello-world].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] 
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector: Unable to respond to any of these 
  challenges: {oauth=OAuth realm="https://api.twitter.com"}
ERROR 2014-01-27 08:57:13,409 [[hello-world].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] 
org.mule.retry.notifiers.ConnectNotifier: Failed to connect/reconnect: Work Descriptor.     
Root Exception was: JSONObject["text"] not found.. Type: class 
twitter4j.internal.org.json.JSONException

ERROR 2014-01-27 08:57:13,412 [[hello-world].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] 
org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to invoke updateStatus. Message payload is of type:
  String

Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. JSONObject["text"] not found. (twitter4j.internal.org.json.JSONException)
  twitter4j.internal.org.json.JSONObject:395 (null)
2. JSONObject["text"] not found. (twitter4j.TwitterException)
  twitter4j.internal.json.StatusJSONImpl:172 (null)
3. Failed to invoke updateStatus. Message payload is of type: String   
(org.mule.api.MessagingException)

  org.mule.twitter.processors.UpdateStatusMessageProcessor:175 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
twitter4j.internal.org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["text"] not found.
at twitter4j.internal.org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:395)
at twitter4j.internal.org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:509)
at twitter4j.internal.json.StatusJSONImpl.init(StatusJSONImpl.java:166)
+ 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was i needed to change the permission to read and write to the twitter application

1. go to application page
2. Settings
3. check  :

[image]